# Call to undefined function mysqli_init() DEBIAN 9

Tags: php, debian, mysqli

Пересмотрел кучу вопросов и попробовал кучу решений, но проблема все равно осталась. Расширение php-mysqlnd тоже установлено

Comment: дак сам модуль `mysqli` то включен? а если в ключен, то в нужном конфиге?

Comment: `phpinfo` что на этот счет говорит? расширение наверняка либо вообще не подключено, либо не смогло загрузиться. поищите чего-нить в логах.

Comment: я раскомментил строку extension=php_mysqli.dll в php.ini, а сам файл находится в /etc/php/7.0/apache2/php.ini

Comment: апач то рестартнули после этого? пхпинфо выполнили? наблюдаете там этот модуль? и апач эту версию пхп использует, раз уж на то пошло?

Comment: апач рестартил, но модуля там все равно нет. Да, использует ту версию

Comment: что по этому поводу в логах пхп и апача?

Comment: вот в логах апача - PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'ext/php_mysqli.dll' - ext/php_mysqli.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/ru/mysqlnd.install.php - вы эту страницу читали?, в частности коммент к ней

Comment: нет, сейчас ознакомлюсь

Comment: Попробовал совет данный в комментариях к странице. Все равно не помогло. И еще проблема такая, что она не работает только на определенном проекте. Я пробовал подключить базу к новому проекту, который только создал и у меня все прекрасно работало. Данные заносились в базу и с таким же успехом я мог вытащить их оттуда.

Answer (score 0):

Хм, не знаю с чем могла быть связана данная ошибка, но решить проблему помогла переустановка php. Спасибо всем, кто принимал участие в решении проблемы :)

Comment: А надо было просто установить модуль командой `apt install php7.0-mysql` ну или какой вы там пакетный менеджер используете.

Comment: он был установлен